# query FQL in javascript for messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-fql

I want to create a very simple app that shows all my facebook messages on screen using FQL and JS.
The [JS docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/howto/jquery) at FB API doesn't help very much, Is there a way to use FQL in it. I am done till the authorizing part in which I logs in and it says user is logged not sure how to use FQL here
Any help

Comment: How is RequireJS a factor in this question?

Comment: @Louis facebook has a JS for require JS

Answer (score 0):

```
FB.api("/fql?q={your query}", function () { 
    // callback 
} );
```

Comment: can you tell me remaining JS as well?

Comment: what remaining JS? Once your user is logged in, use that call.

Comment: I am bit confused , I mean the prevous login call, you know JS is case senstive and a simple comma will create issue